Can you use a MBP as an external display/kb/mouse?
I'd like to use my MBP as a keyboard & display for an external PC.
I have two use cases;

Administering a home server in place
When travelling, taking a mini PC with me for gaming and using my MBP as a screen and keyboard.

The first use case I suppose I could address with something like a Pi-KVM or simply Proxmox's web interface & containers/vms.
The second case is a bit tricky. I could use Steam streaming over the network but it's hard to get a reliable connection when travelling (can Steam streaming be done over usb-c?).
Ideally, a simple kb/display passthrough would be ideal as that would have minimal latency and the highest quality - but I don't think there is any way to do that but I am hoping I am wrong.
Is this possible at all?

remote desktop? VPN?

These are two different questions because the use cases for them are significantly different. I answered the question you asked initially. Your second question, being different, should be removed. I recommend doing some research regarding that second use case before asking the question.

This is, literally, what remote desktop or remote control tools are made for. And that is using "literally" in its correct meaning.
There are a variety of questions on this site regarding using the keyboard, mouse, and/or screen of a laptop as a remote keyboard/mouse/display for another computer, but these tend to be high-latency applications when they DO work, and not really helpful.
The limits of a remote desktop/control solution are usually that you cannot access or control the server outside the fully-booted OS. If you need to access or control the server in the firmware or other pre-boot environments, you will need to do that in person, unless this is an actual server that has an Integrated Lights Out solution included, such as HP's iLO, or Dell's iDRAC.
With those limits in mind, look at your server's OS and either use the built-in remote toolset available, or choose from the many various, often free for home use, remote desktop/control tools available online.
